# Select by pair of fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+-------+-------+-------------+
|column1|column2|   column3   |
+-------+-------+-------------+
|   2   |   4   |    row 1    |   < compare with this
|   4   |   3   |    row 2    | + < here`s 4
|   5   |   2   |    row 3    | + < here`s 2
|   1   |  NULL |    row 4    | - < no 4 or 2
|   5   |   6   |    row 5    | - < no 4 or 2
|  NULL |   2   |    row 6    | + < here`s 2
+-------+-------+-------------+
```

The problem is how to find all rows, that contain at least one searched value. For example I need to find rows like first, so I`m looking for rows with 2 or 4 in first two columns. So my output should be rows 2,3 and 6. I do not need to find NULL values.

Please advise.

Comment: The problem is we don't know which row is the first. Remember that the server inserts the row randomly. I think you need to search for a record first then compare the result on all the rows in the tables. The only time you can get the first row is **to filter the record**, example `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE column3 = 'row 1'`

Comment: My apologies, I used first row just for reference. I will know values to search. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from foo
where (   2 in (col1, col2)
       or 4 in (col1, col2))
and (col3 <> 'row 1')
```

SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd81/5

Alternatively to get it more dynamically:

```
select t.*
from foo t
join (
  select col1, col2 
  from foo 
  where col3 = 'row 1'
) r1 on r1.col1 = t.col1 
     or r1.col2 = t.col2
     or r1.col1 = t.col2
     or r1.col2 = t.col1
where col3 <> 'row 1'
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fd81/3

Comment: Oh, just tried to implement. What if we have NULL value in row1? MySQL reports error, when gets empty space:     _.. OR _ IN(col1, col2).._  Is there any workaround or it will be better to filter it in php?

Comment: @VitalyMirsky: try the second statement, that will deal better with NULLs

Comment: thank you. I don`t understand it and cannot implement, but will try to)

Comment: @VitalyMirsky: Why do you use an empty (NULL) value for the condition `OR _ IN(col1, col2)` in the first place? It doesn't make sense.